# Stress testing of SQL Server Analysis Services tabular model

Tags: ssas, performance-testing, profiler, ssas-tabular

I have a tabular model in SSAS. Before deploying to production I would like to test the performance of the model in the way: How many users can use the model without any performance issues. When all the resources of the server will be exhausted and so on. I know that I can measure actual traffic with Profiler of Extended Events but is there any tool that can simulate traffic of e.g. 50 users? Or is there any way how can I multiple the saved trace from Profiler and replay it with a simulation of e.g. 50 users?

Thanks a lot